# Electric range clicking noise

Tags: electrical, range

When I turn on the oven or any of the 4 knob controlled burners of the cooktop of my electric only kitchen range it makes a clicking noise. I unplugged and tried again. Still clicking. I flipped the breaker and tried again. Still clicking.

I am not skilled in any area of home improvement. II don't attempt any repair myself that involves electricity and don't know what to look for visually. Before I call the big box about servicing the range because of the clicking, I wanted to post these images and would appreciate opinion or advice as to whether the clicking problem might be presenting because of the surface receptacle wiring. Is there a reason I might consider calling a licensed electrical contractor before I set up a range inspection / repair?

We got a new range installed (I think in 2019) in a different location than the previous electric range (It is a small kitchen so the new range is not far from \where the old range was placed. But the new range is connected on the wall driectly across from where the previous stove was placed.

I never looked at what was going on behind this range or the range that was here when we bought the house. I only pulled the newest range away from the wall yesterday so I could unplug it when the clicking sound started.

The house was built in the 80s and is only electric so there was already a dedicated range circuit. There also must have been an existing and properly functioning receptacle behind the range we replaced.

Is the exposed copper wire grounding that does not need to be insulated? Is it neutral that carries current? Does it look OK at a glance? Is there any obvious reason the clicking might be because of wiring and might want to consider calling an electrician instead of getting the range checked?

Thank you in advance!

enter image description here
[image]

Comment: Can you show the front of that receptacle as well, please? **The cable is NOT properly clamped. None of those wires should be showing, the clamp should be on the gray cable jacket, only.** Whether that wire is a ground or a bare neutral is an open question for range or dryer wiring in a 1980 house in North America, unfortunately. For a 2019 install it *should* be ground, but then, the cable clamp *should* be installed correctly, too...and it's not...

Comment: The clicking is new behavior? Do the range and/or oven elements get hot? Is this coils, glass-top, halogen, induction, or what sort of electric range?

Comment: Thank you so very much for the understandable, thoughtful, detailed answers

Answer (score 1):

The clicking could just be the thermostatic controls for the burners.  They're like little switches that open and close at a rate depending on how much heat is being called for.  Note that some stoves/cook tops may have solid state controls (like a light dimmer) and so won't make any noise when they turn on and off.

As for that bare copper wire that's showing in the picture, I think that's an earth ground connection.  It needs to be connected to the metal chassis/housing of the range (which it is, through the cable clamp), but I'm not sure that's code compliant.

That is NOT the neutral (white, usually) wire, and should not be carrying any current at all unless there is a fault in the range that causes the hot conductor (black or red) to come in contact with the chassis.

Answer (score 0):

The unclad copper wire should be a ground wire. It's fine if that's exposed, though I would have clamped the cable an inch or two further up so the wires separated inside the stove and the clamp was riding the outer cable sheath. Might be worth considering fixing that.

Clicking, as others have said, may be the stove cycling the heating elements on and off. Traditionally, electric stove elements were either full on or full off, and a simple timer controlled temperature by controlling how much time was spent heating or not heating. If this is what's happening, the speed if the clicking in the middle of the temperature range should be faster than at the extremes, I think.

Your user manual may have a debugging page which lists common questions; clicking is likely to be one of those.